# How to handle dynamic page sizes in pagination?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to click the following page sizes: 
showing 75 / 150 / 225 / 300 / all of 328 document types

```
<div class="p-paginator-right-content">
    <div class="page-size-list">
      "showing"
      <span class="page-size-item active">75</span>
      <span class="page-size-item ">
        ::before
         "150"
      </span>

def click_page_size(self, size):
all_sizes = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('span[class*="page-size-item]')
for item in all_sizes:        
        if size == item.text:
            item.click()
```

"all_sizes" print out: showing 75150225300all of 328 document types
Error: 
    for item in all_sizes:
TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable

Comment: It hasn't come back as a list.  find_elements will return if at least 1 item is there.  If you're expecting more, it could be these elements are still loading (via client-side script).  Not familiar with Python, but you could type/initialize all_sizes to a list of webelements first.  If the list is still loading options, you'd need to add a wait, or use a webdriverwait and catch stale element exception to re-run if necessary...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than looping through all elements, i would suggest to find the right element dynamically and click on it.

```
size = '75'
mySize = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class,'page-size-item')][contains(text(),'"+size+"')]")
mySize.click()
```